# "No module named pypr.clustering python" when trying to install PyPR

Tags: python, installation, package

I am trying to install the PyPR package in python on Ubuntu.

I found ["Getting PyPR"](http://pypr.sourceforge.net/getting_pypr.html) information. This navigated me to [PyPR](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pypr/files/) website to download the package, but i do not know how to install it as I continue to receive the error:

> No module named `pypr.clustering.python`

when I try to install it.

Comment: Try downloading pypr-0.1rc3.tar.gz from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pypr/files/, unpack the download, cd into it and run 'sudo python setup.py install'.  If on windows just run 'python setup.py install' preferably as administrator.

Comment: Thank you. But again `No module named pypr.clustering`

Comment: However I can see the pypr folder in "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages" address, but again the same message

Comment: Thank you, Done by changing directory.

Comment: pypr.clustering.gmm.cond_dist as documented on pypr.sourceforge.net/auto/pypr.clustering.html is in   pypr-0.1rc3.tar.gz\pypr-0.1rc3.tar\pypr-0.1rc3\pypr\clustering\gmm.py and  pypr-0.1rc3.tar.gz\pypr-0.1rc3.tar\pypr-0.1rc3\pypr\clustering is the clustering module (as viewed in 7-Zip).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue also when downloading the zip file. I ended up adding the PyPR folder to the python path.

I added this to ~/.bashrc

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/python_lib/pypr/
```

When using, change the path to the downloaded or cloned folder.